# SQL explicit and implicit permissions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

If default '`sa'` account has `sys_admin permissions` for the whole SQL instance and all its databases. On the database itself,  if I don't have `db_datareader` permission enabled, I would assume it doesn't need it as it is implied but I was wondering in .net, is there way to check if `db_datareader` has explicitly been enabled and not just implied from the '`sa'` being a `sys_admin.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

play around with the syspermissions catalog:

```
SELECT u.name, o.name
FROM syspermissions p, sysobjects o, sysusers u
WHERE p.id = o.id
AND u.uid = p.grantee
AND o.xtype = 'U' --user
```

Also, you can use these scripts to get Permissions of youe Username / Userlogin on Server / Database

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER');

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE');
```